# How to test router code that contains heavy logic using sinon and stubbing (nodeJS)

Tags: sinon

I am new to using sinon, so sorry if my question is weird, I looked everywhere but can't find a way to do it.

I have app with express router. I want to write uint test for one of the routes. That route have an inner function that is 'heavy', meaning that it is async with promise, and in reality calls an external api. I want to stub that inner function in the test so that it will not use the api, and will return my own data instead of  the original method.

This is the code so far:

routes/setOrder.js:

```
// the inner function I want to stub
var verifyPayment = function(saleId) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    logger.info(`verifyPayment: ${saleId}`);
    externalAPICall.get(  // <==this is the 'heavey part!!
      saleId,
      function (error, sale) {
        if(error) {
          return reject(`Error querying sale(${saleId}): ${error}`);
        }
        resolve(sale);
      });
  });
}

router.get('/paymentId/:paymentId', setOrderWithGet);

const setOrderWithGet =async function(req, res, next) {
    const  { paymentId } = req.params;
    verifyPayment(paymentId)
      .then(async sale => {
        try {
          console.log(`sale:${sale}`);
          res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": "ok!" }));
        } catch (err) {
          logger.warn(err)
          res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": "fail.."}));
        }
      })
      .catch(reason => {
        logger.warn(`[] Payment(${paymentId}) is not valid ${reason}`);
        res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": "fail.."}));
      });

}

module.exports = router;
module.exports.setOrderWithGet = setOrderWithGet;
module.exports.verifyPayment = verifyPayment;
```

setOrderTest.js:

```
const setOrderStub = require('../routes/setOrder');

describe("POST /setOrder", () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
      sinon.stub(setOrderStub, 'verifyPayment').resolves({....});
    });
    afterEach(() => {
      sinon.restore();
    });

    describe("test1", () => {
        it("setOrder first attempt", () => {
            let req ={params : {'paymentId' : 'mypamentid1'}};
            setOrderStub.setOrderWithGet(req,{});
        });
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```js
sinon.stub(setOrderStub, 'verifyPayment').resolves({....});
```

...stubs the `verifyPayment` function on the **module exports** of the `setOrder` module.

---

Right now `setOrderWithGet` is calling the `verifyPayment` function directly, so it is unaffected by any changes to the **module exports**.

---

Change `setOrderWithGet` to call `verifyPayment` using the **module exports**:

```js
const setOrderWithGet = async function(req, res, next) {
    // ...
    module.exports.verifyPayment(paymentId)  // <= call the module export for verifyPayment
    // ...
}
```

...and your stub will get called.